# logstash combine multiple inputs (msql+beat) data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

We need to fetch some information from logs then on the basis of that info, fetch the related details from mysql and index the all details in Elasticsearch.

E.X.
1)log file contain user u1 check the the product p1.

2)Now need to fetch the details (from mysql) of user u1 and product p1 along with the date and time of event occurred (from log file).

3)Need to combine log info along with the Msql details and index the data in Elasticsearch.

Comment: This will be an expensive Query. You have to create two indexes first and join them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59921816/joining-two-indexes-in-elastic-search-like-a-table-join